# Android Studio 403 Forbidden error on gradle sync under proxy

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

I'm in Android Studio.
I need to add necessary dependencies to my project.
I'm under an authenticated proxy.

My gradle.properties configuration in my project looks like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=my.proxy.host
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.http.proxyUser=myUser
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=myPassword
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=cha.jovenclub.cu

systemProp.https.proxyHost=my.proxy.host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.proxyUser=myUser
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=myPassword
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=cha.jovenclub.cu
```

But when I start to sync it returns me 403 Forbidden error when downloading the dependency, specifically this:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.2.71/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.jar'.
at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:89)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:81)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:133)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:66)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:477)


Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/ab88dab9bd2a3c31c4e6aaa0eb4168d13f126e9076561bb42f5f3fe80c902a78?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.2.71.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYWI4OGRhYjliZDJhM2MzMWM0ZTZhYWEwZWI0MTY4ZDEzZjEyNmU5MDc2NTYxYmI0MmY1ZjNmZTgwYzkwMmE3OD9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmtvdGxpbi1ncmFkbGUtcGx1Z2luLTEuMi43MS5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE1NDQ1NjM0Nzd9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=BDTjM-~StUfVLL-JmPIj4hniCxalejSsb6honjOR45AbXxxdK-u2axgBZ2cNY~sRI7jSoIlgv57tyAIOz3SI-vHYr4rjV9NqAEdU7RxwAFG8L8pGa9qvmYX8x9h6EUTncqGIedJzCwc5MK77PrApKO5eejkDwDiLsn7GQCnVKDagqdLSaa-e9WtZjecOcE89sOeWXlA3Eed907AG2FDIqbmAMVXt8qRDK3r7sKhiMZv3P6l6CG9X3kPuUB6t144BNseBYL1rvyOFJ-F-7JBT0zvP6aCLg6i13FpLnZU4MxX7sSDsFvCoOf2RXA0ottASB~MAxg6tU2R-Dq5nRcvQtQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

I'm not pasting the entire error because this is the most important part

Now, if I take the dependency URL (the .pom or the .jar file) and paste it in the browser (firefox, chrome) then it returns me the file correctly.
Of course, the browser is under the same authenticated proxy too.

So, no problems with the browser but Android Studio fails in retrieving the same file.

My sysAdmin is willing to help me but he needs to understand what to do exactly, where does the problem come from.
For security reasons, getting rid of the proxy is not an option.

I really would appreciate help because I can't work if project doesn't sync.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#gradle-plugin